# Usb not working on RPI4B

Tags: usb, keyboard, usb-hub, mouse

Keyboard and mouse and hub not working. I have acess via SSH and VNC though my laptop. The pi cannot see all that. I tried lsusb but nothing shows up except

```
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 2109:3431 VIA Labs, Inc. Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub`
```

I tried dmesg:

```
[ 4397.741090] usb usb2-port4: over-current change #4578
[ 4397.861527] usb 1-1-port2: over-current change #4578
[ 4397.981123] usb usb2-port1: over-current change #4579
[ 4398.101467] usb 1-1-port3: over-current change #4578
[ 4398.221179] usb usb2-port2: over-current change #4579
[ 4398.341536] usb 1-1-port4: over-current change #4580
[ 4398.461112] usb usb2-port3: over-current change #4579
[ 4398.581533] usb 1-1-port1: over-current change #4577
[ 4398.701114] usb usb2-port4: over-current change #4579
[ 4398.821538] usb 1-1-port2: over-current change #4579
[ 4398.941128] usb usb2-port1: over-current change #4580
[ 4399.061650] usb 1-1-port3: over-current change #4579
[ 4399.181141] usb usb2-port2: over-current change #4580
[ 4399.301554] usb 1-1-port4: over-current change #4581
[ 4399.421134] usb usb2-port3: over-current change #4580
[ 4399.541493] usb 1-1-port1: over-current change #4578
[ 4399.661133] usb usb2-port4: over-current change #4580
[ 4399.781570] usb 1-1-port2: over-current change #4580
[ 4399.901259] usb usb2-port1: over-current change #4581
[ 4400.021578] usb 1-1-port3: over-current change #4580
[ 4400.141137] usb usb2-port2: over-current change #4581
[ 4400.261593] usb 1-1-port4: over-current change #4582
[ 4400.381161] usb usb2-port3: over-current change #4581
```

etc. I am using Pi4B 4G. it worked before great. What is happening and what am I doing wrong?
Rebooted that thing a million times.

Comment: You have reached the limitation of these things the USB implementation leaves a lot to be desired is the polite way of putting it. If I plug my keyboard in it fails to boot most times. To say I am unimpressed is a mild understatement. Try plugging it in after boot that seems to work for me...

Comment: It seems you've got a short on the USB ports. Try removing everything and start plugging in one device after the other. The device that first fails is probably broken.

Comment: `it worked before` ... before what?

Comment: Ok I'll try. Thanks HappyTux and PMF. I can shh and vnc tho. I don't know before what

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks @PMF. My keyboard was spamming data in the rpi which caused my mouse and any usb device connected to rpi not work. Here I give PMF's awnser:

```
It seems you've got a short on the USB ports. Try removing everything and start plugging after boot in one device after the other. The device that first fails is probably broken. – PMF Feb 17 at 5:59
```

Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

That is classic over voltage and if you need all of the USB devices you have connected at once is to use a powered USB hub then plug all of your external USB into that.

In that way the USB devices take power from the HUB not the RPI.

Comment: Ok I'll try thnx